# .NET Core Requirement in ASP.NET Core Development and Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am asp.net MVC Developer from last 4 years along with AngularJS, and also had done some MEAN Stack Programming as well. (Understands Lodash, Git, MongoDB, Mongoose, Express, Grunt)

But I had not touched ASP.NET Core yet. But I would like to know do i require knowledge of .NET Core to work with ASP.NET Core.

(I had knowledge of .NET, is it that much different that will make me learn it again and will be more benefited if I know .NET Core only) Or I can just skip that part and start coding and learn as i required.

What do i need to learn extra for Entity Framework Core (I am already using Entity Framework 6 for my development)

Answer (score 2):

.NET core is rewritten, cross-platform .NET framework. It's like asking if when you can ride a mountain bike, do you have to learn a lot to ride BMX.

If you can develop "classic" .NET applications, you will be able to use .NET Core. There will be some differences of course, but nothing **really** different - as for now .NET Core doesn't support everything like "full" .NET Framework (and perhaps it never will, because of his cross-platform nature and because is meant to be a subset of classic .NET Framework)

Answer (score 0):

Read  overview article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/index

and pay attention on

> .NET Core is a general purpose development platform maintained by Microsoft and the .NET community on GitHub. It is cross-platform, supporting Windows, macOS and Linux, and can be used in device, cloud, and embedded/IoT scenarios.
>
> .NET Core is composed a .NET runtime, a set of framework libraries, a set of SDK tools and language compilers, the 'dotnet' app host, which is used to launch .NET Core apps

and this:

> Compatible: .NET Core is compatible with .NET Framework, Xamarin and Mono, via the .NET Standard Library.
>
> .NET Core can be thought of as a cross-platform version of the .NET Framework, at the layer of the .NET Framework Base Class Libraries (BCL). It implements the .NET Standard Library specification. .NET Core provides a subset of the APIs that are available in the .NET Framework or Mono/Xamarin